# Maximum value for Julia integer types

Tags: types, integer, julia, boundary

Julia `Integer` types have a minimum and maximum [value](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/).
When calculations go beyond those boundaries, results are 'incorrect'.

```
for i in Int8[5, 10, 15, 20]
    println(i, " -> ", i^2)
end
```

Result:

```
5 -> 25
10 -> 100
15 -> -31
20 -> -112
```

> Is there an efficient way in Julia to raise an exception when this occurs?
> This to prevent this from happening without noticing.

Maybe there are better solutions than raising an exception.

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/SaferIntegers.jl and `Base.Checked` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia normally does not error on integer overflow as this results in faster code execution (and this is how arithmetic works on the CPU level)

You can however use `@saferintegers` macro to control the overflow.

```
julia> using SaferIntegers

julia> @saferintegers begin
       x = Int8(19)
       y = x * x
       end
ERROR: OverflowError: 19 * 19 overflowed for type Int8
```

In case of loops you need to use one of `Safe*` types:

```
julia> for i in SafeInt8[5, 10, 15, 20]
           println(i, " -> ", i*i)
       end
5 -> 25
10 -> 100
ERROR: OverflowError: 15 * 15 overflowed for type Int8
```

And the second option (perhaps less convenient):

```
julia> ⨰ = Base.Checked.checked_mul;

julia> Int8(9) ⨰ Int8(9)
81

julia> Int8(19) ⨰ Int8(19)
ERROR: OverflowError: 19 * 19 overflowed for type Int8
```

Comment: How should the @saferintegers macro be used in the loop from my question? It does not seem to give me the Overflow Error from your example.

Comment: Suprisingly this macro seems not to handle loos. You can do instead: ` for i in SafeInt8[5, 10, 15, 20]`